# Cordova Failed to find ANDROID_HOME variable (UBUNTU)

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu, build, release

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm trying to build a Ionic 2 app using:

```
sudo cordova build android --release --nofetch
```

It brings me the error:

> Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting
>   setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'.
>   Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

If I use `printenv ANDROID_HOME` it brings me `/home/evolution6/Android/Sdk`
same way: `printenv PATH` brings

```
/home/evolution6/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
/home/evolution6/Android/Sdk/tools
```

My project settings are:

```
    @ionic/cli: 3.16.0 
    cordova CLI: 7.1.0

   Local packages: 
    @ionic/app-scripts: 3.0.1
    Cordova Platforms: android 6.3.0 
    Ionic Framework: ionic-angular 2.2.0
   System:
    Android SDK: 26.1.1
    Node: v6.11.5
    npm: 3.10.10
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that when I used sudo to build android my PATHs to ANDROID_HOME was gone.

Then I solved this firstly, running the command in this dirty way:

```
sudo ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk cordova build android --release --nofetch
```

I solved this by setting chown to cordova

```
sudo chown -R USER:USER /home/[USUARIO]/.cordova
```

Then I was able to run:

```
cordova build android --release --nofetch
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Then add:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

export ANDROID_HOME=/home/USER/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools

export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle-5.2.1
export PATH=${PATH}:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
```

... change USER with your user

Restart bash

```
source ~/.bashrc
```